# API data pulled and plotted onto excel via the xlsxwriter is not being recognized in the chart.add_series() function

Tags: excel, api, charts, xlsxwriter, cryptocurrency

So I'm pulling public data from coingecko's API through a pycoingecko library and am able to plot a specific crypto's historical price in excel. But when I try to create a line chart via the chart.add_series() function, I keep getting an error stating:

xlsxwriter.exceptions.EmptyChartSeries: Chart1 must contain at least one data series. See chart.add_series().

It's like as if it can't read the API data...

Any help?

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import datetime
import xlsxwriter

Workbook1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('HNS_Price_Chart.xlsx')
Worksheet = Workbook1.add_worksheet()

Chart1 = Workbook1.add_chart({'type':'line'})


Worksheet.write('A1','Date')
Worksheet.write('B1','Price')

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
results = cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(id='handshake',vs_currency='usd',from_timestamp=1577836800,to_timestamp=1593820800)

y = 1

for p in results['prices']:
    Worksheet.write(y,0,datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(p[0]/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    Worksheet.write(y,1,p[1])
    y += 1

Chart1.add_series({
    'Categories':'=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$144',
    'Values':'=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$144',
    'name':"HNS Price"
})

Worksheet.insert_chart('D1',Chart1)

Workbook1.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `categories` and `values` options should be lowercase. Changing to the following should work as expected:

```py
Chart1.add_series({
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$144',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$144',
    'name': "HNS Price"
})
```